# Is 'ounces to a pound' a grammatically correct prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm stuck between 'in a pound' and 'to a pound'. (Also, kindle autocorrect thinks prepositional isn't a word)

Comment: It depends on the **CONTEXT!!!**

Comment: There are quite a few Google hits for "ounces to the pound", but more for "ounces in a pound".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would use "in a pound," though both are technically correct.

Comment: Both are syntactically correct, but their semantic correctness depends on the context where they are used.  They **do not** mean the same thing.